# не сработает dropdown... в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: html, bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: что значит не работает? Кидает ошибку? ничего не делает? работает не так как ты ожидал?

Comment: dropdown - это выпадающее меню, оно НЕ срабатывает - т.е. не выпадает меню при нажатии на кнопку...

Comment: есть ли ошибки в консоли браузера?

Comment: пишет Not found favicon.ico ...но я здесь скинул ПОЛНЫЙ код и в нем  нет упоминания favicon.ico

Comment: Конечно ты тут **НЕ** кинул полный код: в твоем сниппете не загружены стили самого бутстрапа, font-awesome, и твои кастомные `mystyle.css`.

Comment: мои стили пусты, а стили бутстрапа все дефолтные!зачем их сюда размещать?

Comment: _зачем их сюда размещать?_ - чтобы у тебя получился пример, который каждый может запустить и убедиться, что действительно не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном коде нет возможности узнать какой версии `bootstrap.css`.

Так как используется `bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6`, то и css должна быть соответствующей версии.

Если ее брать с CDN - все работает:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо, Grundy,  все-таки лучше исполоьзовать ссылки на библиотеки